# Safari: is there a way to setSelectionRange not focus element on which it changes selection?

Tags: html, safari

I am building a datepicker and there is a problem with keyboard navigation. When navigation on calendar panel, while selecting the day, I also update the input value. And I use also setSelectionRange to handle selection inside the input properly (it is input with a mask).

In chrome everything is fine, but in safari after changing the day in the calendar panel, during updating the input, setSelectionRange is executed, which also moves focus to the input. I'd like to avoid that.

I can do some workarounds but I have a question like: is there clean way to not focus input element when using setSelectionRange in safari?

Comment: Isn't that the behaviour expected _by definition_? If you select something the user's input is going to be there, so the focus would be as well. If you want the input to be unfocusable, you could use something like `tabindex=-1`, no?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is expected by definition. In chrome or firefox it does not appear. Yeah, `tabindex` would be also the solution, but it si more like workaround

Comment: It'll be a workaround in any case. It just seems that when selecting text, the selected text (and its wrapping container) would therefor be focused. But safari is a bit of a deviation on that front tbh.

Comment: yes, I've noticed. Thanks for replying anyway